# How to not show the module name in the side bar "project view"

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, intellij-14

In Maven, it is not mandatory to have folder's name mirroring the name of the artifactId.  For example, you could have:

```
myproject
| > pom.xml  (artifactId: myproject)
|__ mysubfolder
    | > pom.xml  (artifactId: myproject-mysubfolder)
```

In this case, folder's name and Maven artifactId are not the same.  From what I understand, IntelliJ will derive it's module's name from artifactId (you will end up with a `myproject-mysubfolder.iml` file).

**The problem**

If you have such a configuration, IntelliJ will end up displaying folder's name and module's name in the side bar "Project view":

```
mysubfolder [myproject-mysubfolder]
```

However, on a navigation perspective, all I care about is the folder structure.  Is it possible to display only the folder's name and do not show the module's name?

Comment: Can you just go in `Project Structure` -> `Modules` and rename the submodule to `mysubfolder` ?

Comment: Btw doesnt intelliJ derive it's module's name from the `<modules>` section in the parent pom?

Comment: @vikingsteve, well, yes, it's possible to do that but what if you have multiple Maven modules with the same artifactId in the same project (they can still be differentiated by groupId). IntelliJ doesn't work with 2 modules with the same name.

Comment: Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: @y.bedrov I actually didn't think about looking for existing issues about that.  Couldn't find one so I filled a new one https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-182363. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to hide module names in Intellij, however it's a global parameter.

1. Open `Help` -> `Edit Custom Properties`
2. `idea.properties` will open. Add following line: `ide.hide.real.module.name=true`
3. Restart IntelliJ

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82965 has more details.